# JS - Inserting row with button works, button does not

Tags: javascript

I have a table where users can add, edit and delete rows via a modal. When adding a new row using this JS:

```
        if (tit.innerHTML === "Add Account"){
          var type=document.getElementById("modal_type").value;
           var price=document.getElementById("modal_price").value;

           var table=document.getElementById(tableId);
           var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
           table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='acc_row"+table_len+"'><td class='accname' id='acc_name"+table_len+"'>"+type+"</td><td class='accbal' id='acc_balance"+table_len+"'>"+price+"</td><td class='edtbutton' style='display: block'><button class='edit_account' data-modal-target='#modal' id='editaccounts' onclick='sayedit()'>✎</button></td></tr>";

           document.getElementById("modal_type").value="";
           document.getElementById("modal_price").value="";
       }
```

A new row is added with correct classes, id's etc. However the edit button that is added does not work. I took a look in developer mode and the edit button that is added is identical to the ones there by default. Here is the function that is supposed to run when clicking the edit button:

```
const openModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-modal-target]");
const closeModalButtons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-close-button]");
const overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

openModalButtons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget)
    openModal(modal)
  })
})

//Modal functionality

$(function () {
    // add click action to your edit buttons
    $('.edit_account').on('click', function(e){
        // get the parent table row
        row = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;

        // get cell data
        c = row.childNodes;
        name = c[0].textContent;
        amount = c[1].textContent;

        // populate modal with data from selected table row
        document.getElementById('modal_type').value = name;
        document.getElementById('modal_price').value = amount;

        // pass table row ID to the modal
        document.getElementById('row_num').value = row.getAttribute('id');
    });
```

Any idea where my mistake is? I tried adding another onclick in the html that is added which causes the modal to open but it doesn't have any functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was addressing a static parent element. In this case:

$('.acc_table').on('click', '.edit_account', function (e){

Answer (score 1):

you add your button after the `$('.edit_account').on('click', function(e){...}` ran so it didn't add the event listener to the button. if you want to add to the new button an event listener you should do it after its created.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do this? Do I add a new function?

Comment: in the if statement you can write after you insert the HTML with the button this:
`document.getElementById('editaccounts').addEventListener('click', func)` and fuc would be the function that runs when you click on the button

Comment: Sorry still a bit stuck. For func would I paste function(e){...} from above? I also tried:.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const modal = document.querySelector(button.dataset.modalTarget)
    openModal(modal)
  })"

Or do I need to write a new function?

Comment: func should be the function you want to invoke once the button with the above id is clicked. what's the error? is the id `editaccounts` unique to the button?

Comment: Should it be the function name or the whole function code? I don't really understand. I made a codepen with the eventlistener here (all the way at the bottom): https://codepen.io/schinken82/pen/poyMezW

The ID "editaccounts" is used for one edit button in each row and an add button below the table. They should all open the same modal, but with variations (e.g the modal title)