# JavaScript Has Already parsed...is there a way to re-run/ reparse my code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reload

I have created a page that is used to track daily tasks. A button is pressed and a new task is created. Within these new tasks, none of the code I have written applies to them as it only appears to work on the tasks that already exist.

Is there a way to reparse/ re-run the code so it recognizes newly created elements and allows them to function?

```
//This is the card that represents a task..'Finish' button is what I am having the issues with.
<section id="active-projects">
      <header>
        <h2>Active Projects</h2>
      </header>
      <ul id = 'active'>
        <li
          id="p1"
          data-extra-info="Got lifetime access, but would be nice to finish it soon!"
          class="card"
        >
          <h2>Finish the Course</h2>
          <p>Finish the course within the next two weeks.</p>
          <button class="alt">More Info</button>
          <button>Finish</button>
        </li>
```

```
//This is the logic that creates a new button by cloning the cards and then applying an event listener that moves it to the finished column upon clicking

createNew () {
    const newClnIds = [];
    const newItem = document.getElementById('active').querySelector('li');
    const cln = newItem.cloneNode(true);
    cln.id = "p" + (document.querySelectorAll("#active > li").length + 1);
    let clnId = cln.id;
    document.getElementById('active').appendChild(cln);
    
        
    //Selects the Finish Button in the New Cloned Element and adds eventlistener to move it to the finished projects column when clicked.

    const clnButton = cln.querySelector('button:last-of-type');
    clnButton.addEventListener("click", function() {DOMHelper.moveElement(cln.id, "#finished-projects ul");
```

```
//This is the function that switches the button from 'Finished' to 'Active'. Pressing 'Finished' moves the card to the 'Active' column and pressing 'Actvive' Button moves it to finished. My new elements will not have the button switch types when pressed to move columns. 

connectSwitchButton(type) {
    const projectItemElement = document.getElementById(this.id);
    let switchBtn = projectItemElement.querySelector('button:last-of-type');
    switchBtn = DOMHelper.clearEventListeners(switchBtn);

    
   
    switchBtn.textContent = type === 'active' ? 'Finish' : 'Activate';
    switchBtn.addEventListener(
      'click', 
      this.updateProjectListsHandler.bind(null, this.id)
    );
  }
```

```
//This is in a Class that is first in my code and is the logic used to move the cards using append.

//receives element ID and a New destination in the DOM and sends the card to that destination Via Append.
  static moveElement(elementId, newDestinationSelector) {
    const element = document.getElementById(elementId);
    const destinationElement = document.querySelector(newDestinationSelector);
    destinationElement.append(element);
    
  }
}
```

Comment: Mainly I am searching for a way to re-run the code without refreshing the page...

Comment: First, instead of explaining what your code does, always post all the relevant code that you are asking about in your question since there are many ways to write code that does what you are explaining. But, in general, if your code is written within functions, the functions can just be re-invoked when needed.

Comment: You're probably having a problem with event handlers not working on newly-created elements. The solution you're looking for is called "event delegation".

Comment: @ScottMarcus my next step was to post the code I am working on shortening it since the last time I post it I was told it was too long. It is written using Classes and functions as an OOP exercise. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks @Pointy I will look into that term and see what I can learn about it!

Comment: @Pointy I have added the code I was mentioning...I am attempting to have the connectSwitchButton function apply to the newly created elements.

Comment: If you create a DOM element, insert it into the DOM, and add and event listener to it, the event listener should just work.

Comment: this `this.updateProjectListsHandler.bind(null, this.id)` looks a bit odd to me. Why would you bind a method to null? Normally, I would expect it bound to `this`.

Comment: @RichardHunter so I attempted to add the event listener, using the same logic that was used on the existing cards, to the new ones..basically copying it and was still having issues which seemed like the easiest answer to me. Then I attempted to use an eventlistener to call on the logic from the previous cards so I wasn't using double code and that is where I became stuck. I think I am lacking some knowledge on calling event listeners.

Comment: A note here: if you bind your event listeners to the parent element, you won't have to dink around with adding new listeners to new elements, or removing listeners when you remove elements. Just bind one click listener to the parent one time, then event bubbling will deliver all the clicks on child elements to the parent. You check `event.target` to figure out what actually got clicked, react if it's a button or other element you care about clicks on, ignore the rest.

Comment: @ChrisBaker someone mentioned this exact same method of "bubbling" which I am also very interested in learning and trying out....To achieve this would I need to have a Class with a function inside the constructor to initiate this?

Comment: You would use the same method you're using here to bind an event, just once to the #active element (so yeah, in the constructor, where ever it's appropriate so it binds after the element exists). Then in the event handler, you'll get event emissions every time the user clicks any single thing within that element. You can check if `event.target` has the class "alt" if that's the button you wanna target, or the other button (put a class on it so you can distinguish it). I suggest more descriptive class names, or even a data attribute. If `event.target` doesn't have the class, ignore the event.

Comment: @MattLaszcz Here's a small demo, where I am binding the event to the UL element, then only react when a button is clicked. https://jsfiddle.net/r5n2ctxh/

This obviously doesn't include adding new items, but you could easily do so, without concern about the event binding -- one and done.

Comment: @ChrisBaker thanks so much for this as well! Super helpful I am learning a lot today! This project has taken me to places I didn't know it would in a good way

Answer (score 1):

Having played around with your code, I find that it does bind handlers to the newly created items. The problem is that the first item in your list doesn't have any handler bound to it. Someone suggested event delegation, which is certainly possible. Another idea would be to have the initial list empty and the list item that you clone from be kept in memory. You could have a function `createListItem()` which just returns a new list item which you then append to the list.

So the answer to your question is: You don't need to re-parse your Javascript. You can simply create new elements, append them to the DOM, then attach event handlers to them, and that, in fact, seems to be what you're already doing.

```js
function createNew() {
  //  get first li from DOM
  const newItem = document.getElementById('active').querySelector('li');

  //  deep clone this element
  const cln = newItem.cloneNode(true);

  //  give clone a new id
  cln.id = "p" + (document.querySelectorAll("#active > li").length + 1);

  // append clone to end of list
  document.getElementById('active').appendChild(cln);

  //Selects the Finish Button in the New Cloned Element and adds eventlistener to move it to the finished projects column when clicked.
  const clnButton = cln.querySelector('button:last-of-type');

  clnButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //DOMHelper.moveElement(cln.id, "#finished-projects ul");
    alert('click on finish button for list:' + cln.id);
  });
}


createNewButton.onclick = createNew;
```

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  background: antiquewhite;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: dotted 1px grey;
}
```

```html
<section id="active-projects">
  <header>
    <h2>Active Projects</h2>
  </header>
  <button id="createNewButton">create new</button>
  <ul id='active'>
    <li id="p1" data-extra-info="Got lifetime access, but would be nice to finish it soon!" class="card">
      <h2>Finish the Course</h2>
      <p>Finish the course within the next two weeks.</p>
      <button class="alt">More Info</button>
      <button>Finish</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: yes that was initially what I was attempting thanks so much! Along with this I was attempting to add an eventListener to run ``` switchBtn.textContent = type === 'active' ? 'Finish' : 'Activate';
    switchBtn.addEventListener(
      'click', 
      this.updateProjectListsHandler.bind(null, this.id)
    );
  }
```
but I could never get it to work...I am going to try with your advice.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue a few days ago ([JS - Inserting row with button works, button does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64183756/js-inserting-row-with-button-works-button-does-not))

For my the problem was when new item is added the function that adds eventlisteners already ran. The solution was targeting an event-listener to a static parent.

Was this originally:

```
$('.edit_account').on('click', function(e){...}
```

Fixed it:

```
$('.acc_table').on('click', '.edit_account', function (e){
```

In this case acc_table was the static parent and all children with the given class had the code applied to them.

For more info look up event delegation.

Comment: This is probably the problem the OP is having, but jQuery wasn't mentioned.

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was trying to explain in my question I am going to take a look at what you posted not I think I can find the answer there.

Comment: You are using JQuery and the OP hasn't indicated that he is.

Comment: How is it different in js?

Comment: I am not using Jquery But I agree with @Pointy and with what I am reading in the solutions to this post. My event listeners are not working on newly created elements. I should have formatted the question that way. I will try to post some code to see why my event listeners are not applying to newly created elements.

Comment: @MattLaszcz the idea is that you put an event handler on `document` or the `<body>` that looks for events that bubble up, and then check the event target to see if it's one of the elements you care about. If it is, then you run your handler code.

Comment: @Pointy so this event handler on document or body will constantly be checking for new items that bubble up ?

Comment: I have actually gotten the newly created button to work...my problem now is that the newly created button needs to switch between "completed" and "incomplete" that will move it back and forth between columns...I have an event handler that works for this but it only moves in one direction...as I said working hard to simplify my code to post!

Comment: Yes. Every "click" event (or whatever kind of event) will "bubble" up to the top of the DOM. Checking to see if the click was on an item of interest is easy and cheap. The answer above exploits a built-in jQuery feature that does that work for you.

Comment: @Pointy ahhh ok awesome the concept makes total sense to me now I will try to implement something like this...I posted some code as well I hope it is enough..

Comment: @Pointy I think I found a way to do this but would my code need to be in a Class/Constructor to be "constantly refreshing"? I would have to instantiate the class though wouldn't I?

Comment: I agree that the post mentions jQuery out of school, however, this is technically the best solution and general advice here -- use one listener on the parent, then it doesn't matter how many things get added or removed. +1, though to @schinken82 take a note here, try not to use jQuery in an answer unless you see it's being used in the question. I appreciate your suggestion, but it implies that one needs jQuery to do it, which is a big time overkill *just* to "get" event binding, since you get it from vanilla.